# CloudKit Database Query Issue

Tags: database, web, cloudkit

I just started to build a web app, and for some reason I have to use CloudKit and its database for my backend.

I tried a really stupid database query and intended to see the results at frontend. Here is my code :

```
CloudKit.configure({
containers: [{
    containerIdentifier: my identifier,
    apiToken: my api token,
    environment: 'development'
  }]
});

var container = CloudKit.getDefaultContainer();
var DB = container.publicCloudDatabase;

var query = {recordType : 'Request'};

DB.performQuery(query).then(function(response){
  if (response.hasErrors) {
        throw response.errors[0];
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

However, I keep getting this authentication_failed error :

```
cloudkit.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) t {_ckErrorCode: "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED", _uuid: "4ef8ba12-eb00-408f-9a1c-6e8b4de84ec8", _reason: "no auth method found", _serverErrorCode: "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED", _extensionErrorCode: undefined…}
```

I tried to fetch a record with the same code, and it works fine. 
So is the error caused by unlogged in users? If so, Is there any configurations in CloudKit Dashboard to allow users from certain URL to query the database without logging in?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the containerIdentifier value. I had a similar issue when I used the identifier name of the API Token instead of the generated iCloud identifier from the app name. You can also verify your token with the link **Test with CloudKit Catalog**

[image]